# Page layout isn't being installed from managed package?

Tags: managed-package, page-layout

I have metadata that contains a new page layout for Account. When I deploy this metadata to a scratch org, the page layout shows up in the Object Manager as expected. But when I include this metadata in a managed package and install it to an org, the layout does not show up. (But all my other changes show up just fine.) What's going on?

I should mention that I previously installed my layout successfully with an earlier version of the package, but I had to delete the layout in order to uninstall that package. Now when I install the new version of the package, the layout doesn't show up.

Comment: Could be related to record type assignment and you are looking at record with different record type?

Comment: New install or upgrade? Managed package upgrades don't update layouts.

Comment: Raul: The layout isn't showing up in the Object Manager at all, so I don't think the record type assignment has to do with it.

Keith: I have updated my original post with more details. Maybe my situation counts as an update but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the org where managed package installed previously had the package version ? when you say you uninstall , was it uninstall of a specific version or complete uninstall ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava: it was a complete uninstall.

Comment: @IanHorner Sounds like a bug to me .Needs reporting to salesforce so they fix it .

Answer (score 1):

Update: I have not figured out why this problem is happening, but I found a work-around. Just change the name of the layout metadata file, and the layout will install successfully.